# How can I remove shading on a plane but still allow shadows from other objects to be cast on to the pane?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

I have objects on top of an 'Images as Plane' plane and I'd like it to not have any shading/gradients in lighting, so it looks like it would if I opened the image in an image viewer with maximum brightness.

However, I'd still like to allow objects above to cast shadows on to the object. How can I achieve this?

Below, the cube is shaded and casts a shadow on the plane (all good), but the plane should not have any shading on it, since it's brighter in the left compared to top-middle.
[image: shadow]
Below, the plane is bright and this is what I want, but now the cube does not cast any shadow on the plane.
[image: no shadow]
[image: nodes for second image]

Comment: You might have to render 2 separate layers and then join them in the compositor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to use the default *Principled BSDF* setup (using base color, not emission) and change the type of the light source to **Sun**. This way, neither cube position, nor Plane position, will change the colors on the plane (other than the colors of areas that go in or exit the shadow).

[image: GIF with the example]

The reason your examples don't work is that in one case the image is the light, so it can't be shadowed, and in the other you're using a light type with a falloff - simulating the fact that the closer a pixel is to the light source, the more photons from the light source hit that pixel - for the same reason the Sun heats ground the most at noon on Summer. You can lit a surface equally, if it's a fragment of a sphere, with the light source in the center of the sphere - same logic as with curved PC monitors. As you increase the sphere, given the fragment's surface remains constant, it will be closer and closer to a flat surface as it gets further and further from the sphere's center:

[image: a surface with faces oriented towards a point, flattens, as the point moves further away]

If you want a perfectly flat surface, you need an infinitely far light source, and that's what the Sun light type represents.